# How to decompose the Coulomb potential into Fourier series in a 3d periodic space?

Tags: electrostatics, fourier-transform, crystals, coulombs-law

I want to decompose the Coulomb potential $W\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=1/\left(4\pi r\right)$, in a periodic 3d space of size $L^3$  into a Fourier series
$\hat{W}(\mathbf{k})=\int_{\left[-L/2,L/2\right]^{3}}\text{d}\mathbf{r}\text{e}^{-i\mathbf{k}.\mathbf{r}}W(\mathbf{r})$ such as
$W\left(\mathbf{\mathbf{r}}\right)=\frac{1}{ L^{3}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\text{e}^{i\mathbf{k}.\mathbf{r}}\hat{W}\left(\mathbf{k}\right)$.

My final result is $$\hat{W}\left(\mathbf{k}\right)=\frac{2}{k^{2}}\left(1-\cos \frac{kL}{2} \right),$$where $k$ is the norm of $\mathbf{k}$. However, I find it odd, because I could not see how this result would converge towards the usual result in the large $L$ limit, which is supposed to be $$\hat{W}\left(\mathbf{k}\right)=\frac{1}{k^{2}}.$$

Here are my computations:

> We compute this integral in spherical coordinates
> $$\hat{W}\left(\mathbf{k}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{L/2}r\text{e}^{-ikr\cos\theta}\sin\theta\text{d}r\text{d}\theta\text{d}\phi.$$
> We perform the integration on $\phi$ and we use the change of variable $u=\cos\theta$ such that $\text{d}u=\sin\theta\text{d}\theta$ $$\hat{W}\left(\mathbf{k}\right)=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{L/2}r\text{e}^{-ikru}\text{d}r\text{d}u.$$The integration on u is straightforward and yields
> $$\hat{W}\left(\mathbf{k}\right)=\frac{1}{-ik}\int_{0}^{L/2}\left\{ \text{e}^{-ikr}-\text{e}^{ikr}\right\} \text{d}r.$$
> (Usually here, when we work in infinite space we have $\int_{0}^{+\infty}$... and we do the manipulation $k\rightarrow k+i\lambda$, i.e., compute the Yukawa potential Fourier transform with parameter $\lambda\rightarrow0$ to obtain $\hat{W}\sim\left(k^{2}+\lambda^{2}\right)^{-1})$
> Finally, after integrating over the radial coordinate, we obtain
> $$\hat{W}\left(\mathbf{k}\right)=\frac{2}{k^{2}}\left(1-\cos \frac{kL}{2} \right)$$.

Comment: Spherical coordinates in the box geometry look rather odd, the walls of the box will have rather nasty expression in terms of $(r, \theta, \phi)$

Comment: Oh, absolutely, I can see my mistake. I tried to adapt the computation of the Fourier transform in infinite space but I can see how it could become a problem. Actually, for my problem, I don't really need the formula for the Fourier components, but rather the $\mathbf{small}$ $L$ asymptotics in fact.
Independently, my result should hold for a spherical box of radius $L/2$ I think. Is there a physical argument to bridge with the infinite space result?

Comment: the problem is, that there is no notion of small $L$, because there are no other scales in the theory to compare with, by a simple rescaling, you may set $L$ to 1 or any other value. The Fourier transform is a bit subtle in this case, because it is defined for $L^2 (\mathbb R^3)$ integrable functions.

Comment: Everywhere I wrote $L$, it has to be understood as $L/\lambda_D$ where it is rescaled by the Debye length. I am interested in how the Fourier coefficients of the Coulomb potential scales with the small parameter  $L/\lambda_D$ . For the infinite space case, I am aware of the subtlety and how to derive the Fourier transform in a rigorous way. But I was wondering how this could be related to this spherical case at least.